# viewWillAppear is not executing

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a tableview loaded withe records, see the code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Accounts";
//    NSString *accountFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Accounts2" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts2.plist"];
    accounts = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    NSLog(@"Accounts contains : %@", accounts);
    account = [accounts objectForKey:@"Account"];
    NSLog(@"account %@", account);
    number = [accounts objectForKey:@"Number"];
    dueDay = [accounts objectForKey:@"DayDue"];
    minAmount = [accounts objectForKey:@"MinAmount"];
    balance = [accounts objectForKey:@"Balance"];

    NSLog(@"data loaded"); 

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
//    if (!_objects) {
//        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 //   }
 //   [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
 //   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
 //   [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    if (!self.addView) {
        self.addView = [[AddView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddView" bundle:nil];
    }
          [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.addView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"I am done, now what");
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Number of records is %d", [account count]);
    return [account count];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }


     NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
     cell.textLabel.text = [object description];

    NSString *nameOfAccount = [account objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = nameOfAccount;
    NSString *accountNumber = [number objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = accountNumber;
    NSLog(@"Index %d", indexPath.row);
    return cell;
}
```

I want to add a record to table, so I use the "InsertNewObject" method ... new screen appears, I am able to add the record to my plist, and then I execute the following line in the DetailView to return:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Now, I want to reload my TableView with my new record: 
I thought I just had to have the following viewWillAppear method like below:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear {
    NSLog(@"View will appear");
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

but, my NSLog is never executed, therefore my program is never getting here... am I doing something incorrectly, thank you for any response

I have added the following two methods:

```
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *) navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *) navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

and changed the line

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

still not working, is something still wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As pointed out, viewWillAppear takes an `animated` argument. However, even when you add that, popping a view controller off the navigation stack does not trigger a call to `viewWillAppear:`. You need to use `UINavigationControllerDelegate`'s `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` methods to reload your table view.

Comment: do I use these together, instead of the pop? I am pretty new to this and I am on a deadline. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you still pop, but now you know when that happens by registering the previous view controller as the delegate for `UINavigationController`, allowing it to execute code when the view controller is popped.

Comment: Thank you Scott, appreciate the help

Comment: Scott, I added the methods for willShowViewController and didShowViewControler, I added the interface UINavigationController and I changed the line for POP to animated. Is there still something incorrect? see edits above

Comment: Did you also make yourself the delegate of the navigation controller? (`self.navigationController.delegate = self`)

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the correct method. You are leaving out the `animated` argument, try using **`-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`**:

See [`UIViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - [**`viewWillAppear:`**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear%3a)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"View will appear");
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this affects anything. I've left my code like he did and it worked fine.

Comment: This is how it is done, I do pretty much the same thing in just about every app I use that requires reloading a tableview.

Comment: Also, you left your code like who did? just using **viewWillAppear** with no `animated` argument won't do anything because the `UIViewController` class does not contain such a method.

Comment: What I meant was passing YES as an argument works as well as passing animated.

Comment: OK, passing "YES" or "animated" is not the issue. The issue is that there was no argument in the original question, `-(void)viewWillAppear;` (without the BOOL argument). However, you do not need to pass YES as the argument, either way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a nav controller I belive the correct way to reload a view would be to call  somethihng like this

```
  -(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated 
 { 
   [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

You could also create your own custom `reloadData` method that sets what you want changed and then call that method.

Comment: This answer is correct (`viewWillAppear` takes an argument) - a better approach would be to post a notification or make a delegate callback from your data source in order to trigger a view update.